# What happend to my transaction

Tags: transaction-data, transaction-confirmation, confidential-transactions, poloniex

I bougth some Monero on poloniex to send to my paperwallet some months ago.
Today I checked my paper wallet on mymonero.com and there is balance 0.
When I check my transaction on moneroblocks, it says 
`Confidential Transaction — amounts are not disclosed.`
What does this mean? is there hope for my money or is it lost?

This is the transaction:

```
https://moneroblocks.info/search/faf8a90c43e8f992915a638dd4a544b11f67fe9d0c093907568f9976300d841f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched your transmission hash on XMRchain.org and the coins were sent.

Download the entire block chain to a computer.  Check completion status, and when 100.0%, nothing less, reconstitute your paper wallet into a real wallet, using your 25 word mnemonic seed.  Your coins will magically appear.